# Get values from array with for issue

Tags: powershell

when trying to get a line for each element will retrieve full variable instead of the item.

I've tried foreach and for with the same outcome

```
$test = (Get-Content "xxxx.sdgm") -match "Install,"
    $package =  ($test).replace("Install,", "")
    $first = ($package).substring(0,4)
    $second = ($test).replace("Install,", "").substring(4, 16)
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $first.Count; $i++)
    { 
        "$second[$i]"
    }
```

Expected results:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $second[1]
RAMP0001600WEN00

PS C:\Windows\system32> $second[2]
WEST0005000WEN00

PS C:\Windows\system32> $second[3]
VC101003031WEN00
```

Actual results:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Temp\chuches\testing.ps1
ODFX0001000WEN00 RAMP0001600WEN00 WEST0005000WEN00 VC101003031WEN00 CLNT0010203NEN00 NLS10010202WEN00 ODCR0010050WEN00 STAR0036000WEN00[0]
ODFX0001000WEN00 RAMP0001600WEN00 WEST0005000WEN00 VC101003031WEN00 CLNT0010203NEN00 NLS10010202WEN00 ODCR0010050WEN00 STAR0036000WEN00[1]
ODFX0001000WEN00 RAMP0001600WEN00 WEST0005000WEN00 VC101003031WEN00 CLNT0010203NEN00 NLS10010202WEN00 ODCR0010050WEN00 STAR0036000WEN00[2]
.
.
.
[7]
```

(My main goal is to concatenate $first and $second but i'm stuck on getting it working so $first is just there until i can get it working, the expected result would be "test-path $first\$second" inside that for statement)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the output from the first line is along these lines:

```
$test = @("Install,ODFX0001000WEN00", "Install,RAMP0001600WEN00", "Install,VC101003031WEN00", "Install,WEST0005000WEN00", "Install,CLNT0010203NEN00", "Install,NLS10010202WEN00", "Install,ODCR0010050WEN00", "Install,STAR0036000WEN00")
```

We can do the following. I changed the '16' in the second substring to take the length of the string

```
$test = @("Install,ODFX0001000WEN00", "Install,RAMP0001600WEN00", "Install,VC101003031WEN00", "Install,WEST0005000WEN00", "Install,CLNT0010203NEN00", "Install,NLS10010202WEN00", "Install,ODCR0010050WEN00", "Install,STAR0036000WEN00")

$package =  ($test).replace("Install,", "")
$first = ($package).substring(0,4)
$second = ($test).replace("Install,", "").substring(4, $test.Length)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $first.Count; $i++)
{
    Test-Path "C:\$($first[$i])\$($second[$i])"
}
```

To explain the issue you're having with the string output, instead of outputting a single object from the array, you're outputting the full array each time. This because of the quotes.

If you remove the quotes around `$second[$i]`, it will give your expected result.

```
$test = @("Install,ODFX0001000WEN00", "Install,RAMP0001600WEN00", "Install,VC101003031WEN00", "Install,WEST0005000WEN00", "Install,CLNT0010203NEN00", "Install,NLS10010202WEN00", "Install,ODCR0010050WEN00", "Install,STAR0036000WEN00")

$package =  ($test).replace("Install,", "")
$first = ($package).substring(0,4)
$second = ($test).replace("Install,", "").substring(4, $test.Length)
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $first.Count; $i++)
{
    $second[$i]
}
```